# Guessing lucky number assignment

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, while-loop

Can't seem to get the code to work on `if player_guess in player_lucky_list:`. It does not check if I had guessed the right number. Also having trouble with the task **d.**

> **d.** If it is a number, and in the list, but doesn’t match
> lucky_number then you find out number(s) that has max
> difference as is 10, and assign the numbers that has 10
> difference into list input_diff and add the lucky_number if
> it was not in the list, then write out:
> “your number is 10 points more or less from these
> numbers : {input_diff}, do you like to try again? (type ‘Y’
> = yes, ‘N’ = no)”

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import random


def age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))


player_fname = input("Name: ")
player_age = int(input("Age: "))

running = True
while running:
    player_birthday = datetime.strptime(input("Birthday (format yyyymmdd): "), "%Y%m%d")
    age_player = int(age(player_birthday))
    if age_player == player_age:
        print("Wow your age is right, let’s continue!")
        running = False
    else:
        print("Aha, we are in 2022 and your age is not right, kindly enter it again?")

lucky_number = random.randint(1, 200)
tries_count = 0

player_lucky_list = []
n = 10
for i in range(n):
    player_lucky_list.append(random.randint(0, 200))

player_lucky_guess = []
guessing = True
while guessing:
    message = "Hi {}, this is your try # {}".format(player_fname, tries_count)
    print(message)
    player_guess = input("Please enter number from {}: ".format(player_lucky_list))
    if player_guess in player_lucky_list:
        print("Congratulations, your lucky number is {} you got it from try # {}".format(player_guess, tries_count))
    elif str in player_guess:
        print("Sorry, wrong value, Enter a INTEGER NUMBER!!!!")
    else:
        print("Try again")
    tries_count += 1
    player_lucky_guess.append(player_guess)
    print(player_lucky_guess)
```

Comment: `player_guess = input(...)` should have an `int()` around the `input()` like you have elsewhere. Also this is one question per post; if your other issue is a separate question, then ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Regarding your line "elif str in player_guess", take a look at exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Your list is storing different int values.  The input function defaults to accepting strings.  So you need to convert the string of "player_guess" into an int.

```py
while guessing:
    message = "Hi {}, this is your try # {}".format(player_fname, tries_count)
    print(message)
    player_guess = input("Please enter number from {}: ".format(player_lucky_list))
    if int(player_guess) in player_lucky_list:
        print("Congratulations, your lucky number is {} you got it from try # {}".format(player_guess, tries_count))
    elif int(player_guess) not in player_lucky_list:
        print("Sorry, wrong value, Enter a INTEGER NUMBER!!!!")
    else:
        print("Try again")
    tries_count += 1
    player_lucky_guess.append(player_guess)
    print(player_lucky_guess)
```